# Using Node 12 with npm 7

Tags: node.js, npm

We are trying out npm 7 new features. We use it with Node 12. Anyway, it doesn't support Node 14.

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.8.0
```

In the official documentation, it should be used with Node 15.

So is it a bug of Node 12? Or is it really Node 12 compatible and I can't find it in documentation?

Comment: If it isn't compatible with Node 14, why do you expect it to be compatible with Node 12? However, I can't find any mention about there being a version restriction.

Comment: I'm not expecting it, but it's actually is. So I was wondering if anyone has the same experience. 'cause npm7 is new and not much used

Comment: What problems do you experience when using npm 7 with node 12?
Could you add a link to the documentation page mentioning that npm 7 does not support node v14?

Comment: I'm experiencing no problems with Node 12 and npm 7. But it seems to be wrong 'cause it should not be supported. If it's supported officially, then it's no problem. But it's doesn't

Comment: I've only seen that is says "shipping with Node 15.0.0". That doesn't mean that it only works with 15.